# 'KeyError' when merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, api, machine-learning

Trying to do machine learning for a video game I play to predict the upcoming prices to give an insight on whether its worth keeping

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

headers = {"User-Agent": "Hohman#4134 - ML project"}
prices_url = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/latest"

try:
    prices_response = requests.get(prices_url, headers=headers)
    prices_response.raise_for_status()
    prices_data = prices_response.json()
    prices_data_df = pd.DataFrame(prices_data)

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print("Error: Could not retrieve prices data. Please check your user agent.")
    prices_data_df = pd.DataFrame()

ids_url = "https://prices.runescape.wiki/api/v1/osrs/mapping"

try:
    ids_response = requests.get(ids_url, headers=headers)
    ids_response.raise_for_status()
    ids_data = ids_response.json()
    ids_dict = {}
    for item in ids_data:
        ids_dict[item['id']] = item['name']

    ids_data_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ids_dict, orient='index', columns=['name'])

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print("Error: Could not retrieve IDs data. Please check your user agent.")
    ids_data_df = pd.DataFrame()

merged_df = pd.merge(prices_data_df, ids_data_df, left_on='id', right_index=True)

item_name = input("Enter the name of the item: ")
item_data = merged_df[merged_df['name'].str.contains(item_name, case=False)]
latest_price = item_data['high'].iloc[0]

print(f"The predicted price of {item_name} is {latest_price} GP.")
```

This is the error

```
  line 33, in <module>
    merged_df = pd.merge(prices_data_df, ids_data_df, left_on='id', right_index=True)
  line 110, in merge
    op = _MergeOperation(
   line 703, in 
    ) = self._get_merge_keys()
   line 1195, in _get_merge_keys
    left_keys.append(left._get_label_or_level_values(k))
 line 1850, in _get_label_or_level_values
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'id'**
```

I tried that but got the same result which was just named name that time. I have no clue whats going on.

```
merged_df = pd.merge(prices_data_df, ids_data_df, left_on='name', right_on='name')
```

Comment: Try to `print(prices_data_df, prices_data_df.columns)` to find out what it contains and which columns.

Comment: "prices_data_df" only contains one column "data" and "ids_data_df" only contains one column "name".

Answer (score 0):

The **id** column is missing in the **prices_data_df** data.

The way you create the **prices_data_df** is also wrong. The **prices_data_df** contains only one column **data**.

Modifying the code of prices_data_df in the below way will solve the issue.

```py
try:
    prices_response = requests.get(prices_url, headers=headers)
    prices_response.raise_for_status()
    prices_data = prices_response.json()
    prices_data_df = pd.DataFrame(prices_data['data']).T
    prices_data_df['id'] = prices_data_df.index.astype('int')

except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
    print("Error: Could not retrieve prices data. Please check your user agent.")
    prices_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
```